# Plot hours taking into account dates

Tags: r, datetime

I would like to plot the mean hour this people go to sleep vs how much they feel rested. The problem is that some bedtime are after midnight, and in these cases the mean is calculated without taking into account that the bedtime is from the next day, like in row 80 of the following dataset.

```
         Bed_Time_time           Rested 

70 2023-11-22 22:30:00     Occasionally 
71 2023-11-22 22:00:00  Often or always   
72 2023-11-22 21:30:00  Often or always 
73 2023-11-22 21:00:00 Some of the time 
74 2023-11-22 21:30:00 Some of the time 
75 2023-11-22 23:59:59      Hardly ever 
76 2023-11-22 22:45:00     Occasionally 
77 2023-11-22 22:00:00 Some of the time 
78 2023-11-22 22:30:00     Occasionally 
79 2023-11-22 21:45:00     Occasionally 
80 2023-11-23 01:00:00            Never
```

I have tried the following code, but if the bedtime is after midnight, the mean bar is not right.

```
bed_time <- data %>%
  mutate(Hour = hour(Bed_Time_time)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(
    factor(Rested, levels = c("Never", "Hardly ever", "Occasionally", "Some of the time", "Often or always")),
    Hour,fill = Rested )) +
  stat_summary(geom = "bar", fun = mean, width = 0.6) +
  geom_errorbar(stat = "summary", width = 0.5) +
  labs(title = "Bed Time", x = "Rest Feeling", y = "Bed Time") +
  theme_classic() +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0)
```

Comment: Where have you tried to adapt `Bed_Time_time`  to cases like row 80?

Comment: You need to tell us how you'd like to handle post-midnight bedtimes.  You've told us what's "not right" but not what *is* right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subtract the date from the date-times to leave you with column of difftimes. You then average *these* and add the date back on.

```r
library(tidyverse)

data %>%
  mutate(time = Bed_Time_time - as.POSIXct('2023-11-22')) %>%
  group_by(Rested) %>%
  summarise(Bed_Time_time = mean(as.POSIXct('2023-11-22') + time)) %>%
  mutate(Rested = factor(Rested, c("Never", "Hardly ever", "Occasionally", 
                                   "Some of the time", "Often or always"))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Bed_Time_time, Rested, fill = Rested)) +
  geom_col(width = 0.3) +
  scale_x_datetime('Mean bed time') +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = as.POSIXct(c('2023-11-22 21:00:00',
                                      '2023-11-23 02:00:00'))) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = 'Set1') +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16)
```

[image]

---

**Question data in reproducible format**

```r
data <- structure(list(Bed_Time_time = structure(c(1700692200, 1700690400, 
1700688600, 1700686800, 1700688600, 1700697599, 1700693100, 1700690400, 
1700692200, 1700689500, 1700701200), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = ""), Rested = c("Occasionally", "Often or always", 
"Often or always", "Some of the time", "Some of the time", "Hardly ever", 
"Occasionally", "Some of the time", "Occasionally", "Occasionally", 
"Never")), row.names = c("70", "71", "72", "73", "74", "75", 
"76", "77", "78", "79", "80"), class = "data.frame")
```